# empty interface(abstract class) for logical grouping of objects to avoid LSP violations

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, polymorphism

In the real world a square is a rectangle, but to a program this is not the case([LSP principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).  is it considered an anti-pattern / poor programming to create a blank interface to logically group objects together?  My thought is with a blank interface it would be impossible to violate the `LSP` at the level directly beneath it.   Contrived example below.

```
Abstract class Canine{ }  

Dog extends Canine {…} 

Wolf extends Canine {…}
```

Comment: If Canine is "blank" (no methods), how do you use polymorphism through it?

Comment: "In the real world a square is a rectangle, but to a program this is not the case" - that's not quite right. Both in the real world and to a program assuming a suitable hierarchy, an immutable square is an immutable rectangle. Both in the real world and to a program, an "object that can be altered to represent any square and nothing else" is not an "object that can be altered to represent any rectangle and nothing else", and that's where a naive attempt at polymorphism violates LSP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends what it's for.

An empty interface imposes no syntactic requirements, since there are no methods to implement.

But the interface might be documented to impose *semantic* requirements, especially if `Canine` itself inherits from `Canoidea` or `Carnivora` or whatever. This makes the empty interface potentially useful since it provides guarantees of its own. All Carnivora have ears[*], but Canoidea are characterized in part by some property of their ears that isn't easily expressed as simply as adding a method, so implementing the interface becomes a promise: "in addition to being a Carnivora, my ears behave like that".

That means it's no longer impossible to violate the LSP. You could accidentally write a subclass with an overridden function that returns 12, which is permitted for Carnivora, but the semantics of Canine say that it won't return more than 10.

Interfaces that add only semantics aren't necessarily great to work with, since there are certain mistakes that it's easy to make. An example is the difference between `InputIterator` and `ForwardIterator` in C++ (although of course those are template concepts, not inherited interfaces). If you tag your class with the wrong one, the compiler will never notice. But if you tag your class with `RandomAccessIterator` when really it's only a `ForwardIterator`, then the compiler *will* notice, when someone tries to use `operator+` on it, since `operator+` is part of RandomAccessIterator but not ForwardIterator.

An empty interface with no semantics is meaningless, and hence probably useless. The only use for it I can think of is as a kind of variant - some dodgy code could test whether the object is an instance of "Dog" or "Wolf" (or something else), and do different things accordingly. That's probably not a good use since it's probably not good code in the first place. You might as well use an ultimate superclass like `Object`, if available, since either way the code is going to have to cope with types that it doesn't recognise and can't handle. "What on earth is a Fox, I can't use a Fox here" is no better or worse than "What on earth is a Vector, I can't use a Vector here", so if what you understand is dogs and wolves, there's no real advantage to accepting a `Canine` compared with accepting an `Object`. They're both variants which allow Dogs, Wolves, plus anything else someone chooses to slot into the hierarchy.

[*] Yes, even seals. They just don't have pinnae.

Comment: so just to confirm, an empty interface is appropriate when it enforces semantics

Comment: Yes, it can be. If there's some way to express the difference in terms of method signatures, even if the only difference is a covariant return type, that's probably better. But if there's a useful subset of the interface that's pure semantics, the resulting sub-interface will be empty.

Answer (score 2):

No it will not break LSP since there's nothing that can be done with the base, and therefore it's not possible for any of the classes to violate LSP.

I do sometime use empty interfaces to group classes together. I do so to show some intent. For instance, I got an empty interface called `IMessage` which is used to show that the purpose of a class is only to be handled as a message in my pub/sub framework. (And only classes which implements the interface are allowed to be transported in it).

For me, it helps to make sure that classes follow single responsibility principle. (compared to a message class which do not implement any interfaces)

Answer (score -1):

In your scenario how does this help us. We have an abstract class Rectangle? What is it that prevent us from claiming that Square extends Rectangle?

Comment: A class can always extend another one, even if the base class is empty or not. Nothing will ever prevent that.

Comment: marking the class final could, but that defeats the purpose of the exercise